# List current Principals in group Managed Service Accounts

Tags: active-directory, powershell

Is there a way to list the current list of all the groups and/or hosts in the `PrincipalsAllowedToRetrieveManagedPassword` property of a gMSA (group Managed Service Account)?

There isn't any help on the "[Getting Started](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj128431.aspx)" page, what is more [their](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj128431.aspx#BKMK_AddMemberHosts) [examples](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj128431.aspx#BKMK_DecommMemberHosts) are returning errors and are not very clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It [turns out](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852323.aspx) that you can list all the properties for gMSA by running:

```
Get-ADServiceAccount -Identity <gMSA-account> -Properties *
```

And if you want to narrow down the list you can use:

```
Get-ADServiceAccount -Identity <gMSA-account> -Properties PrincipalsAllowedToRetrieveManagedPassword
```

It's not very readable, since it's a list of distinguished names and has several other properties listed, but it's a useful command.

**Update:** to show all the entries from this properties you can use this command, which is shorter and easier to handle that what @Gregory posted

```
(Get-ADServiceAccount -Identity <gMSA-account> -Properties *).PrincipalsAllowedToRetrieveManagedPassword
```

You can select specific property, instead of the wildcard *, to decrease the data flowing over the network, but the line becomes prohibitively long due to the verbose name of the property.

Answer (score 1):

If the list of Principals includes an ellipsis (…), then you will need a foreach loop to get the full list:
`Get-ADServiceAccount -Identity <gMSA-account> -Properties PrincipalsAllowedToRetrieveManagedPassword | 
select PrincipalsAllowedToRetrieveManagedPassword | 
ForEach-Object { $_.PrincipalsAllowedToRetrieveManagedPassword }`